# Default value for @Environment property wrapper key path?

Tags: ios, swiftui, environment-variables

I access an environment variable in SwiftUI like this:

```swift
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass
```

When I access these objects inside the views `body` I constantly have to provide a default value like this.

```swift
switch horizontalSizeClass ?? .compact {
   default:
     Text("Size Class Demo")
}
```

How can I provide a default value at a high level so I don't have to use `??` everywhere in my view?

Answer (score 1):

You should not set default value for `horizontalSizeClass` or `verticalSizeClass` they are get value from actual device Screen View that your app is alive! How ever you can set manually a value for them but it's makes no sense, because in that case they would not be correct. `horizontalSizeClass` or `verticalSizeClass`should monitor the size class!

You can use `UserInterfaceSizeClass` with `if` like this:

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass

    var body: some View {

        if verticalSizeClass == UserInterfaceSizeClass.regular {
            
            Text("verticalSizeClass is regular!")
            
        }
        else {        
            
            Text("verticalSizeClass is compact!")
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a computed property that provides the default for you:

```
struct ContentView1: View {
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) private var verticalSizeClass

    var constrainedVerticalSizeClass : UserInterfaceSizeClass {
        verticalSizeClass ?? .regular
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        switch  constrainedVerticalSizeClass {
        case .compact:
            Text("Compact")
        default:
            Text("Default")
        }
    }
}
```